# Regexp to get text with two curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace text "{/w0rd}" with two curly brackets from the following string using a regexp in JS?

**Original**

```
"I need this {/w0rd} from my string"
```

**Expected Output**

```
"I need this apple from my string"
```

Comment: What did you try so far?
If you want to retrieve only this, then you just `return "{/w0rd}";`. So, what's the point? Check if the text contains `{/w0rd}` ?

Comment: I want to replace this word like "I need this apple from my string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `/{.*}/`, to match everything inside two curly brackets. to replace the matched characters you can use `replace()`

```js
var str = "I need this {/w0rd} from my string";

console.log(str.match(/{.*}/g));

console.log(str.replace(/{.*}/g, "apple"));
```

Comment: And to replace the `{/w0rd}` you can use the method [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like so `str.replace(/{.*}/g,"apple")`

Comment: @George question did not mention replacing text earlier, thanks for pointing, answer updated.

Comment: This is perfect, as long as there is only one `{...}` in the input string. As long as has two, like `"I need {two} words from {this} string"`, then the greedy qualifiers bring you to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the word is literal as is, all you need to do is to escape the slash. I.e. add a backslash before that: `\/`:

```
var original = "I need this {/w0rd} from my string";
var replaced = original.replace(/{\/w0rd}/, "apple");
```

If you want to match all the stuff between curly braces, then you can match everything that's not a closing brace:

```
var original = "I need this {/w0rd} from my string";
var replaced = original.replace(/{[^}]*}/, "apple");
```

You can play more on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o3xdoaf/).